# IOUtils.byteArray NoSuchMethodError in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, nosuchmethoderror, ioutils

I am running a unit test in an Eclipse project, and when I run the following JUnit test

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    final byte[] array = IOUtils.byteArray();
    ...
}
```

I get the following error:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.byteArray()[B

I have included Apache commons-io 2.11.0 in my classpath:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
... 
    <classpathentry kind="var" path="APACHE_IO/commons-io-2.11.0/commons-io-2.11.0.jar"/>
... 
</classpath>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe you shouldn’t use a third party library, just to obfuscate the expression `new byte[8192]` as `IOUtils.byteArray()`.

Comment: Have you verified that the class in that jar has that method and signature?

Comment: The issue is that methods in Apache POI use IOUtils.byteArray; the only reason that I put it into setup() is to test the existence of byteArray().

Comment: I have verified that the jar file contains IOUtils.class, and that the sources jar file contains IOUtils.java, and that IOUtils.java contains byteArray().   I have imported the java file into my project, and it worked.  It looks like IOUtils.class may have been built from a different version of IOUtils.java; I will report this as a bug to Apache.

Comment: Hey @DavidGauntt I have run into the same issue now, did you find a work-around?